# Doubt on the definition of topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I need some clarifications on topological manifolds. My professor has defined them as *second countable, connected, Hausdorff topological spaces which are locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n_+$, where $\mathbb{R}^n_+=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R^n}|x_n>0\}$.*

My question is: why do we ask that the target of the local homeomorphisms is $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ and not simply $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Comment: @Clarreta With your definition both would be exactly the same, but one generally defines it (when dealing with manifolds with boundary) to be locally homeomorphic to the upper half-space $\{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n:\, x_n \geq 0\}$, and in this case it is different.

Comment: Also, it's highly unusual to include connectedness in the definition of manifolds.  The statements of a lot of theorems are simpler if manifolds are allowed to be disconnected.